# php mysql search data with multiple keywords

Tags: php, mysql, sql, full-text-search

I currently have my query to have `LIKE('%keyterm%')`. It works fine if my data has one keyboard typed. But what if I want to type in two keywords. Then it will return false.

Example:

```
keyword : rock climbing
data in mysql: Rock Day Free Climb
```

This phrase should come out because it has **Rock** and **Climb** but it seems like LIKE is not enough?

What else would I need to get that query?

Thanks!

Comment: what about LIKE(%rock%) OR LIKE(%climbing%) or if its always first key and second key you can use rock%climbing as keyterm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to split on the whitespace and have a `LIKE('%keyterm%')` statement for each. See [php.net/explode](http://php.net/explode)

Comment: Thanks, you guided me to the right direction. I figured it out

Answer (score 0):

Return results containing either keyword1 or keyword2:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE data LIKE '%keyword1%' OR data LIKE '%keyword2%';
```

Return results containing both keyword1 and keyword2:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE data LIKE '%keyword1%' AND data LIKE '%keyword2%';
```

Comment: I have an OR statement in my query, and I'm searching the keyword as Rock Climbing, not rock then climbing.